# How to preprocess c/h files in Android so that they get the exact CFLAGS and C_INCLUDES as c source are built?

Tags: android, makefile, c-preprocessor

I am parsing some C headers in Android project using pycparser. For pycparser to work, C headers must be preprocessed (cpp or gcc -E).

How do I write an Android.mk to preprocess C headers so they gets the same compile options (CFLAGS, C_INCLUDES) as C sources files would be compiled by Android.mk?

Thanks!

PS:
Run mm showcommands is a way to get actual compile flags manually. Yet I'm looking for a way to intergrate this in automatic build process.

Comment: Did you already fix your problem? I got the same problem as you. I also tried manually use mm showcommands, but it still didn't work when preprocessing. Have you ever success doing preprocessing?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It seems an impossible to me after I read android make system files. 'mm showcommands' works for me though.